# Styled Component does not update the <div> after a re-render

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a react component which renders based on a switch statement.
I am updating the state in which the switch is based out of and it does not

```
switch (condition) {
    case Condition1:
    default:
      return (
        <Condition1Component />
      );
    case Condition2:
      return (
        <Condition2Component />
      );
    case Condition3:
      return (
        <Condition3Component />
      );
  }
```

All three components are being wrapped in its own styled `div`.

When I go from default state to `Condition3` , The `Condition3` component is being wrapped around the `Condition1 styled div` which is strange.

When I change my default state to `Condition3` then everything works as supposed to.

Comment: `default` needs to be the last block in the `switch` statement.

Comment: Hey Yurui , default can be anywhere in the switch case.

Comment: this is a bit difficult to read. I don't think it has much to do with styled-components. Could you provide more code? it'd be great if you could provide a link to an example on codesandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you.

```js
const Container1_DIV = window.styled.div`
  color: red;
`;

const Container2_DIV = window.styled.div`
  color: blue;
`;

const Container3_DIV = window.styled.div`
  color: green;
`;

const Default_DIV = window.styled.div`
  color: black;
`;

function App() {
  
  const [myState,setMyState] = React.useState(1);
  
  switch(myState) {
    case 1:
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Container1_DIV>I am Container 1</Container1_DIV>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(1)}>Select 1</button>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(2)}>Select 2</button>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(3)}>Select 3</button>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(4)}>Select 4</button>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    case 2:
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Container2_DIV>I am Container 2</Container2_DIV>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(1)}>Select 1</button>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(2)}>Select 2</button>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(3)}>Select 3</button>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(4)}>Select 4</button>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    case 3:
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Container3_DIV>I am Container 3</Container3_DIV>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(1)}>Select 1</button>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(2)}>Select 2</button>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(3)}>Select 3</button>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(4)}>Select 4</button>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    default:
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Default_DIV>I am Default DIV</Default_DIV>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(1)}>Select 1</button>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(2)}>Select 2</button>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(3)}>Select 3</button>
          <button onClick={()=>setMyState(4)}>Select 4</button>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
  }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```